# problem in equation beginning

Tags: equations

I wrote the code of the equation but I have an error while writing `Jij`, any help?

[image: equation]

```
\begin{equation}
J_i_j = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \frac{1}{k}exp\left(-\frac{{||x_i - x_j||}^{2}}{{2a}^{2}}\right) \quad x_i is nearest neighbor of x_j,\\
    0 \quad \text{else}
  \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Use `J_{ij}`...

Comment: Hi, it is better to visit [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to use `J_{ij}` instead of `J_i_j` thanks to Werner.

Answer (score 3):

```
 \begin{equation}
 J_{ij} =           %   group subscript with braces
 \begin{cases}      %   use cases macro for piecewise functions
     \frac1K\exp    %   capital K, \exp, you don't have to type braces around single characters
        \left(-\dfrac{\|x_i - x_j\|^2}  {2a^2}\right)   %   \dfrac for display fraction bigger ,\| for double |, less braces   
        & x_i \text{ is nearest neighbour of } x_j,\\   %   use & in cases mode, 
     0  & \text{else}                                   %   \text{} 
 \end{cases}
 \end{equation}
```